# MySQL new row appears after deleting row record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have very strange issue, when I try to delete a row from the table it comes back with null fields, any idea why this would happen?

The only thing I am doing is

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 1
```

thats all I am doing, then after refresh I can see new row created with all null fields but only supplier id duplicate from previous row.

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26

[image]

Comment: We need more information than this to help.  Something must be inserting a new record.  Off the top of my head, if you were using something like Hibernate, perhaps you are saving an entity which has been stripped of all its fields.

Comment: i checked, there is no triggers or anything, just doing simple delete with in mysql and row comes back with new "id"

Comment: Only two possibilities: Either you are actually doing an _update_, not a delete, or you are deleting the row and then inserting a new one.

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 1 thats all I am doing

Comment: anyone knows what the issue ?

Comment: You need a recursive CTE here, but I don't know the exact answer.

Comment: Did you commit the transaction? Otherwise, close and reopen your viewing tool.

Comment: i was doing this in software, phpmyadmin, or in actual backend code and still creates this row I dont  know why is it doing that, other tables I have they not creating new rows only happening in this table.

Comment: Make copy of this table into another table.. and try deleting the rows..

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to close this question, adding the same as answer

Make copy of this table into another table.. and try deleting the rows.

Comment: check related tables,  delete triggers something is adding data back